# How to use the Configure widget in Algolia's InstantSearch

Tags: algolia, instantsearch.js, react-instantsearch

I need some help using Algolia's Configure widget.
I'm using React InstantSearch Hooks in a Gatsby project and I'm looking to only retrieve during a search results that were created more than 15 minutes ago.
Here is a snippet of my component:

```
<InstantSearch
        searchClient={algolia.searchClient}
        indexName={algolia.indexName}
        initialUiState={restrictions ? {
            [algolia.indexName]: {
                refinementList: restrictions,
            }
        } : undefined
        }
    >
...
        <Configure numericRefinements={{
            createdAtTimestampInSeconds: [{ operator: '<', value: ['fifteenMinutesAgoInSeconds'] }]
        }} />
        {children}
    </InstantSearch >
```

My results contain createdAtTimestampInSeconds to allow using NumericFilters.
I did not find anything in the doc and my syntax does not seem good, it does not respect OperatorList type.
If you have examples or the correct method, I take it.
thanks in advance